# Misalignment in window join of two data streams Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm collating some result on a daily basis.

I did window join on my data with a window size of 1 day.

There are two kafka data sources: A and B.

I need to do a filtering for A and remove duplicates for B before they join.

```
        KafkaSource A = new KafkaSourceConfig("topic-A").buildSource();
        DataStream<ObjectNode> a = env.fromSource(source, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks());
        a = a.filter((FilterFunction<ObjectNode>) objectNode -> {
            String tableName = objectNode.get("key").get("table").asText();
            return tableName.matches("table_A");
        }).assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
                WatermarkStrategy.<ObjectNode>forMonotonousTimestamps().withTimestampAssigner((objectNode, l)->{
                    String updateTime = objectNode.get("value").get("data").get("db_update_time").asText();
                    return DateTime.parse(updateTime, DateTimeFormat.dateFormatSecond).getMillis();
                })).filter((FilterFunction<ObjectNode>) objectNode -> {
            String status = objectNode.get("value").get("data").get("status").asText();
            return status.equals("SUCCESS");
        }); 


        KafkaSource B = new KafkaSourceConfig("topic-B").buildSource();
        DataStream<ObjectNode> b = env.fromSource(source, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks());
        b = b.filter((FilterFunction<ObjectNode>) objectNode->{
                    String tableName = objectNode.get("key").get("table").asText();
                    return tableName.matches("table_B");
                })
                .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
                        WatermarkStrategy.<ObjectNode>forMonotonousTimestamps().withTimestampAssigner((objectNode, l)->{
                            String insertTime = objectNode.get("value").get("data").get("insert_time").asText();
                            return DateTime.parse(insertTime, DateTimeFormat.dateFormatSecond).getMillis();
                        })).keyBy(o->{
                                String asset = o.get("value").get("data").get("base").asText();
                                return asset;
                })
                .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.days(1)))
                .process(new ProcessWindowFunction<ObjectNode, ObjectNode, String, TimeWindow>() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(String s, ProcessWindowFunction<ObjectNode, ObjectNode, String, TimeWindow>.Context context, Iterable<ObjectNode> iterable, Collector<ObjectNode> collector) throws Exception {
                       // process and collect
                    }
                });
```

And the window join happens

```
    DataStream<Datapoint> s = a.join(b)
                .where(o -> {
                    return o.get("value").get("data").get("currency").asText();
                })
                .equalTo(o-> {
                    return o.get("value").get("data").get("quote").asText();
                })
                .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.days(1)))
                .apply(new JoinFunction<ObjectNode, ObjectNode, Tuple3<String, BigDecimal, BigDecimal>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Tuple3<String, BigDecimal, BigDecimal> join(ObjectNode o1, ObjectNode o2) throws Exception {
                        // return values
                    }
                })
```

My problem is that the two data stream are not in sync when reading from kafka. datastream B will have consistent incoming data on a daily basis (because i'm using a cronjob for data collection) but there is no guarantee that datastream A will have consistent daily incoming data. On some days there will be a lot of data coming in but on other days there might be no data.

I tested a bit and observed that the program seems to be blocking at the window join function.

Want to ask if there is a way to solve this issue. Thanks for the help!

Comment: blocking means when i try to do a print statement in the `join` function, nothing is printed.

Comment: Can you see any records emitted from A and B before joining through UI?